# How do I wait for a List<Mono> to get resolved?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I want to be able to wait for a List of Monos to get resolved and upon completion of the last element, proceed with another async call

```
public Mono<Artist> getArtistInfo(String id) {
    //Call API1
    Mono<MusicResponse> musisResponseMono = webClientBuilder
                                                .build()
                                                .get()
                                                .uri(uri + "\\" + id)
                                                .retrieve()
                                                .bodyToMono(MusicResponse.class);

    //1.async handler for the first call
    return musisResponseMono.flatMap(musicRes ->{

        Artist artist = new Artist();

        List<Albums> albums = musicRes.getAlbums();

        //make mutiple concurrent API calls to API2
        albums.stream().forEach( album -> {
            webClientBuilder
                .build()
                .get().uri("API 2 URL")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Covers.class)
                .subscribe(cover -> artist.getAlbums().add(cover.getImage()));
        });


        //call API3 - want to wait untill all API calls 2 are completed
        return webClientBuilder
            .build()
            .get()
            .uri("API3 URL")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Profiles.class)
            .map( profileRes ->
                artist.setDescription(profileRes.getDescription())
            );


    }
    
}
```

The problem is that API call 3 may return before every element of the second call is returned . I guess what I'm looking for is something like asycn await in Javascipt in the context of Spring Webflux

Comment: Could you improve your code snippet? It's hard to provide the right answer because it really depends on how you're using (or not) the intermediate responses. You don't need to provide everything, but it would be really useful to add meaningful types (not response1, response2) and actually use intermediate results where you need them. For example, mbid, the album response, etc aren't used

Comment: If I somehow find a way to aggregate a the List<Mono> to Mono<List<Albums>>, I think I could then find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work.

We first fetch the artists and map the response. During the mapping we fetch each album cover and get a `List<Mono<Cover>>` bock.

We then merge these in a `Flux#merge` that will emit each `Cover` when they are available. So we can then on each emit `doOnNext` and attach these to the artist.

When that is done, we just `then` and return the artist object.

After these chain of events we can `doOnSuccess` our second fetch and attach more information to the `Artist` object.

```
public Mono<Artist> getArtistInfo(String id) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/artist")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ArtistResponse.class)
            .flatMap(artistResponse -> {
                final Artist artist = new Artist();
                return Flux.fromIterable(artistResponse.getAlbums())
                        .parallel(2)
                        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                        .map(albums -> webClient.get()
                                .uri("artist/albums")
                                .retrieve()
                                .bodyToMono(Covers.class))
                        .doOnNext(coversMono -> coversMono
                            .doOnSuccess(covers -> artist.getAlbums().add(covers)))
                        .thenReturn(artist);
            })
            .doOnSuccess(artist -> webClient.get()
                    .uri("/artist/profile")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Profiles.class)
                    .doOnSuccess(profiles -> artist.setDescription(profiles.getDescription())));
}
```

Havn't run the code so can't guarantee it but at least it will give you some insight maybe and a step on the way.

Comment: The problem is I either go through every element of the list and subscribe with desired operation to that element , in which case I no longer have any Mono on the second call (List) to zipWith or I don't subscribe but return a List<Mono> which I doubt I can use to zip anything to it.

Comment: I was a bit fast there my coffee hadn’t kicked in. Well alist of monos are actually a Flux. So with the merge option you can get rid of the list. I’ll write up a solution when i get home in about 30 mins you can either choose to chain the calls or do the two calls and use zipWith to make sure the calls wait for eachother.

Comment: Thanks Thomas , I was able to get quite a bit of an insight from your snippet, it's exactly what I needed . I was able to slightly tweak your code and get it all working.

Comment: glad i could help